# how to remove duplicated between 2 values?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I have 100.000 lines with information like:

```
K1xxxxx,ttttt,wwwww,xxxxxK2, 
K1hhhhh,sssss,gggg,jjjjjjjK2,   
K1xxxxx,ttttt,wwwww,xxxxxK2,
```

I want the result as:

```
K1xxxxx,ttttt,wwwww,xxxxxK2, 
K1hhhhh,sssss,gggg,jjjjjjjK2,
```

As you see line 1 and line 3 are duplicated. I want to delete all duplicated between K1 and K2.

How can I do this in notepad?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're trying to achieve this in Notepad or in Notepad++? As you've tagged both, it is confusing me a bit as this problem is easy to be solved in Notepad++. If you want to solve this in Notepad++, here is a link to its solution. It is pretty simple: https://heitorhherzog.medium.com/compare-sort-and-delete-duplicate-lines-in-notepad-2d1938ed7009

Comment: The lines are **not** duplicates - the 2nd one does not have a trailing `,`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *I want to delete all duplicated **between** K1 and K2*. For the expected result you have shown in your question (differing from this description) just try ***Edit > Line Operations > Remove Duplicate Lines***.